# How do I undo an ingestion in Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Context: I'm following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-examples

I'm using `IngestFromStorageAsync` - I see that the results have an `IngestionSourceId` (a GUID) - but I don't know what to do with this. (this is not the extent id)

I was assuming that you could use this ID to remove all the records that were imported...

Does anyone know how to undo an ingestion?

---

Currently, I'm using `.show cluster extents` to show the extent ids, then I call `.drop extent [id]`.  Is this the right way to undo an ingestion?

Comment: Comment about `.drop extent [id]` : Yes, but you have to be sure the extent ids you are about to drop contain only the information you ingested (and want to drop). Extent ids have nothing in common with the source ids, as multiple sources can end up in a single extent and the extents are merged to form larger extents. – 
Vladik Branevich  Oct 31, 2019 at 8:25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"undo"ing an ingestion is essentially dropping the data that was ingested.

dropping data can be done at the resolution of extents (data shards), and extents can get merged with one another at any given moment (e.g. straight after data was ingested).

if you know there's a chance you'll want to drop the data you've just ingested (and you can't fix the ingestion pipeline that leads to those "erroneous"(?) ingestions), one direction you could follow would be to use extent tags, to be able to identify the extents that were created as part of your ingestion, then drop them.

more information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/extents-overview.
if you do choose to use tags for this purpose (and can't avoid the situations where you need to "undo" your ingestions), please make sure you read the "performance notes" in that doc.

---

Excerpt from documentation link:

#### 'ingest-by:' extent tags

Tags that start with an `ingest-by:` prefix can be used to ensure that data
is only ingested once. You can issue an **`ingestIfNotExists`** property command that prevents the data from being ingested if there already exists an extent with this specific `ingest-by:` tag.
The values for both `tags` and `ingestIfNotExists` are arrays of strings,
serialized as JSON.

The following example ingests data only once. The 2nd and 3rd commands do nothing:

```
.ingest ... with (tags = '["ingest-by:2016-02-17"]')

.ingest ... with (ingestIfNotExists = '["2016-02-17"]')

.ingest ... with (ingestIfNotExists = '["2016-02-17"]', tags = '["ingest-by:2016-02-17"]')
```

> [!NOTE]
> Generally, an ingest command is likely to include
> both an `ingest-by:` tag and an `ingestIfNotExists` property,
> set to the same value, as shown in the 3rd command above.

> [!WARNING]
>
> - Overusing `ingest-by` tags isn't recommended.
> - If the pipeline feeding Kusto is known to have data duplications, we recommend that you solve these duplications as much as possible, before ingesting the data into Kusto.
> - Attempting to set a unique `ingest-by` tag for each ingestion call might result with severe impact on performance.
> - If such tags aren't required for some period of time after the data is ingested, we recommend that you drop extent tags.
>
>   - To drop the tags automatically, you can set an extent tags retention policy.

Comment: When ingesting with python DataFrame, how can i tag it to later drop it? @Yoni L.

Comment: Kusto's ingestion APIs include a set of [`IngestionProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-properties) that you can set when you invoke the ingestion. One of those properties is `Tags`.